# GA UTM tracking ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Facebook group which want to promote my website and looking for some tracking tool for Google Analytics. I found campaign URL builder https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/ which can track links with UTM.

The problem is how to track people who come through this link to my website and purchase. Because when somebody come through this link and click on product the UTM tracking is lost.

Is there a way to track all actions through this UTM link? Preferably I want to track only eCommerce enhanced. Thanks!

Comment: Can you say what exactly you mean by "UTM tracking is lost"? It sounds that you are worried because the parameter is no longer in the URL. That does not really matter, though - UTM parameters need to be set only on the landing page. GA will attribute transactions to the source that was set on the landing page in a a session.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. When I go to landing page the UTM parameter is there but when I click on any other page or product the UTM is lost in the URL. So it will track all purchases?

Comment: It shoud track correctly.

Comment: You can add your first comment as answer :) thanks